# Getting a list of iterations for a given release

Tags: rally

I'm trying to make a custom app that pulls all the iterations for a given release.  I'm not seeing how this can be done.

Any Ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific please.

Comment: What version of AppSDK are you using, 1.x or 2.x? Do you have some starting code that you need help on?

Comment: Sorry - I am trying to retrieve the list of iterations that belong to a provided release.  The display the iterations with the app.

Comment: Using AppSKD 2.x.  Sorry, no code as of yet. Still trying to determine the relationship between Iteration and Release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a code example, check out this code from PlanPlanPalatable. It uses AppSDK 2.0 to build a tree of iterations, based on a chosen release.

https://github.com/RallyCommunity/PlanPlanPalatable/blob/master/IterationsAndReleases.js

Answer (score 4):

There is no coded relationship between releases and iterations. However, if you're just looking for iterations which fall within the same time box as the release, you could query for iterations using the release's StartDate and EndDate properties as criteria for the iteration start and end dates. One thing to keep in mind: when you query for iterations, you're going to get a unique entry for each iteration : project combo. If you have a lot of projects set up which all share the same iteration schedules, you're going to get a large set of results which, in your context, represent the same thing.